# Failed to rename ; Access denied Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to  build a machine learning code with tensorflow 2.0 in jupyter using the mnist dataset . The data set is being taken from tensorflow-datasets but during the initial downloading of the dataset  , after it downloads its showing an error that it is unable to rename the dataset and then aborting the whole process.

this is the line used for loading the dataset

`mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)`

and this is the error

```
Downloading and preparing dataset mnist (11.06 MiB) to C:\Users\Main\tensorflow_datasets\mnist\1.0.0...
Dl Completed...:
0/0 [00:00<?, ? url/s]
Dl Size...:
0/0 [00:00<?, ? MiB/s]
Extraction completed...:
0/0 [00:00<?, ? file/s]






WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\file_format_adapter.py:209: tf_record_iterator (from tensorflow.python.lib.io.tf_record) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use eager execution and: 
`tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)`
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\file_format_adapter.py:209: tf_record_iterator (from tensorflow.python.lib.io.tf_record) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use eager execution and: 
`tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6bf2983938fb> in <module>
----> 1 mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\api_utils.py in disallow_positional_args_dec(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
     50     _check_no_positional(fn, args, ismethod, allowed=allowed)
     51     _check_required(fn, kwargs)
---> 52     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54   return disallow_positional_args_dec(wrapped)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\registered.py in load(name, split, data_dir, batch_size, in_memory, shuffle_files, download, as_supervised, decoders, with_info, builder_kwargs, download_and_prepare_kwargs, as_dataset_kwargs, try_gcs)
    298   if download:
    299     download_and_prepare_kwargs = download_and_prepare_kwargs or {}
--> 300     dbuilder.download_and_prepare(**download_and_prepare_kwargs)
    301 
    302   if as_dataset_kwargs is None:

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\api_utils.py in disallow_positional_args_dec(fn, instance, args, kwargs)
     50     _check_no_positional(fn, args, ismethod, allowed=allowed)
     51     _check_required(fn, kwargs)
---> 52     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54   return disallow_positional_args_dec(wrapped)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py in download_and_prepare(self, download_dir, download_config)
    305         self.info.size_in_bytes = dl_manager.downloaded_size
    306         # Write DatasetInfo to disk, even if we haven't computed the statistics.
--> 307         self.info.write_to_directory(self._data_dir)
    308     self._log_download_done()
    309 

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    117         if type is None:
    118             try:
--> 119                 next(self.gen)
    120             except StopIteration:
    121                 return False

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\file_format_adapter.py in incomplete_dir(dirname)
    198   try:
    199     yield tmp_dir
--> 200     tf.io.gfile.rename(tmp_dir, dirname)
    201   finally:
    202     if tf.io.gfile.exists(tmp_dir):

C:\Python38\Anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in rename_v2(src, dst, overwrite)
    506   """
    507   _pywrap_file_io.RenameFile(
--> 508       compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite)
    509 
    510 

UnknownError: Failed to rename: C:\Users\Main\tensorflow_datasets\mnist\1.0.0.incompleteI3ZU6X to: C:\Users\Main\tensorflow_datasets\mnist\1.0.0 : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
```

Comment: possibly because of the anaconda restrictions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309013/tensorboard-checkpoint-access-is-denied-input-output-error

Comment: The problem is solved  after running    pip  install -U tensorflow-datasets in the preferred conda environment . But  if someone could point out whether  -U in that line represents update or not would rather be more helpful .

Comment: -U indicates upgrading "all specified packages to the newest available version.
The same problem occurred to me, but `pip install -U tensorflow-datasets` didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A GitHub issue has been open in order to solve it.

In that thread, a temporal solution is presented, although it implies modifying some TensorFlow functions by hand. I am not sure about whether it will have an impact in model performance, but I will let the link posted below in case you want to give it a try:

[Windows - tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to rename: #41380](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41380)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. Just change the `data_dir` attribute like `data_dir=r"D:\data"` and make sure it should not be in `C: drive`. You are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Changing disk or data directory didn't work for me (Win10).

However, specifying the version of the dataset worked.

Example:
`tfds.load(name='celeb_a:2.0.0',... )`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while running locally. I assume the error is due to read and write permissions of the folder in which the data is being downloaded and stored.

I fixed it by specifying the data_dir parameter in the tfds.load() function to a folder where special user permissions won't be required.

here is my function call:

```
mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name='mnist', data_dir='C:/', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

this will create a folder for the data in the root directory instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow/models/MODEL_NAME /

the solution for me was to make sure there is no "checkpoint" in there beforehand, there was a checkpoint folder that is in there for obvious reasons but the script im using(someone elses) they're calling that the ckpt.0 in a different location so i basically moved it to that new location and removed the checkpoint folder from *above path. im an inexperience coder, ESPECIALLY new to python but im currently running the Train Script successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue today. I solved it by updating permissions on the destination folder to include read/write privileges. Initially the folder was read-only.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to get the Tensorflow API 2.0 working and got the same error as above.
I specified the Model folder the same as the Checkpoint folder. To fix the error mentioned above I had to separate the Model and the Checkpoint folder.